# R ggplot2 geom_line specifying colour form a vector returns unknown color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have this piece of code

```
colors = c("score" = "#26648E")
plot = ggplot() + geom_line(data = DT, aes(x = position, y = score), stat = "summary_bin", binwidth = 1000, color = "score", group = 1) + scale_color_manual(name ="", values = colors) + facet_wrap(~chromosome, scales = "free_x")
ttle = paste0("referee score") 
plot = plot + labs(
  title = ttle) #+ theme(plot.title = element_markdown(lineheight = 1.5, size = 12), legend.text = element_markdown(size = 14))
p = plot +xlab( "position") + ylab("")
p
```

which returns

> Error: Unknown colour name: score

It's not the first time I define colours beforehand in a vector and it has always been working. I don't get why in this specific case it doesn't work. I know I could define the colour directly in geom_line, I am just trying to understand why the code doesn't work. For instance I have this piece of code

```
colors = c("heterozygosity" = "#8b0000", "coverage" = "#00919c")
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = CT, aes(x = end, y = 3*(normalize(heterozygosity)), color = "heterozygosity")) + 
  geom_line(data = COV, aes(x = end, y = 2*(normalize(coverage)), color = "coverage")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name ="", values = colors) + 
  facet_wrap(~CHROM, scales = "free_x")
```

That produces no error and gives the desired output.

Thanks for any insight

Comment: Notice that in your second example, `color` is *inside* `aes()` in each geom layer.  In the first it's outside `aes()`, which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

color falls under the aesthic, try placing it after assigning the y-axis. As shown below. It should work

```
colors = c("score" = "#26648E")
plot = ggplot() + geom_line(data = DT, aes(x = position, y = score, color = "score")  stat = "summary_bin", binwidth = 1000, group = 1) + scale_color_manual(name ="", values = colors) + facet_wrap(~chromosome, scales = "free_x")
ttle = paste0("referee score") 
plot = plot + labs(
  title = ttle) #+ theme(plot.title = element_markdown(lineheight = 1.5, size = 12), legend.text = element_markdown(size = 14))
p = plot +xlab( "position") + ylab("")
p
```

Comment: Welcome Alessandro, we are all learning.. Don't get intimidated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

that was indeed quite embarrassing but of course you are right it was just a question of scope.